# Camera intent doesn't work in real device

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

I have a main activity that opens fragment A, Then I open a menu and open fragment B instead:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,String.valueOf(position)).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Fragment B is using the camera with the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
Random r = new Random();
mCurrentPhotoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + r.nextInt(10000) + "image.jpg";
File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);                            
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

in onActivityResult:

```
File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);            
ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

While on the emulator it works perfectly, when running the app on a real device (samsung galaxy s3, android 4.3), 2 weird things happen:

1) if I do take a picture, the app closes and the "unfortunately..." popup appears for no apparent reason and I don't even know where  to begin researching for the problem.

2) if I click on "back" button without taking a picture, it returns back to main activity/fragment A! if then I call again to fragment B, the images (of fragment B) appear but the "background" is transparent through which I see the remains of fragment A.

setRetainInstance(true); is set for all fragments. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: "I don't even know where to begin researching for the problem" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: Is there a way to see the stack trace when running on the device (not connected to the computer)?

Comment: You can try setting up `adb` over WiFi. Not all devices support that, though.

Comment: I wonder if there's an easier way of getting a stacktrace, in case of an exception... and even if so, the second problem is still a mystery.

Comment: "I wonder if there's an easier way of getting a stacktrace, in case of an exception" -- production apps can use any number of services for collecting stack traces. "the second problem is still a mystery" -- at most, only you have any idea what the background is supposed to be, what the background is made of, what the layout is, what the theme is, etc. Use tools like Hierarchy View to determine where you are going wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is because while all inner screens are fragments, the main activity/screen is not a fragment (it contains the frame layout) so when orientation changes, it restarts it causing fragment A to be loaded again. So how can I retain the state of the main activity?